# How to customize error messages for validates numericality sub-options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

How can I customize the error messages for sub options when validating numericality on a field in an ActiveRecord model?

Example:

```
validates :month, :numericality => {
  :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1,
  :less_than_or_equal_to    => 12
}
```

In this case if the 'month' attribute is more than 12, I want to provide custom error message  instead of the default "must be less than or equal to 12". How to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't want to use a custom validator, you could use the `en.yml` file instead. Assuming "post" was your model name, this provides examples for age-specific messages, post-specific messages, and generic (all models) messages.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        post:
          attributes:
            age:
              less_than_or_equal_to: "Age-specific error" # Applies only to post.age
          less_than_or_equal_to: "Post-specific error" # Applies to all other fields for a post
      messages:
        less_than_or_equal_to: "Generic error" # Applies to all other models
```

Comment: But that would mean I cannot customize it across multiple occurrences of 'less_than_or_equal_to' right?.

Comment: What about only_integer?  That key doesn't seem to be working, though :greater_than works when nested in the same place.  EDIT (i.e. ANSWER): Found it in [the source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb#L34): It's `not_an_integer`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the error messaging depending on the model you can use this syntax:

```
validates_numericality_of :month, 
    greater_than_or_equal_to: 1,
    less_than_or_equal_to: 12,
    message: "My custom error message"
```

You can also use this syntax to customize error messages based on the specific conditions:

```
validates_numericality_of :month, 
    greater_than_or_equal_to: 1,
    message: "Too small"

validates_numericality_of :month, 
    less_than_or_equal_to: 12,
    message: "Too big
```

Comment: If using this answer, and the field is given a non-numerical value, this will produce two errors (Too small, Too big), and will not mention the field not being a number.